# Why are all of my booleans setting off as true?

Tags: c++

I tested my code out by printing the values out to see why it did not output the value I should be getting. And I found out all of my booleans that were for the string ride were set off as true and I can not seem to get a clue why. I have tried searching the internet up yet I could not find anything. My understanding of the code is not deep enough for me to understand what is going wrong here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;



int main() {
  //declarations
  string ride;
  char comp;
  int age;
  double td, tp, god, rp, sp, ta, tap;
  bool fer, bump, zip, pir, test;

  //print outs and input
  cout<<"What ride would you like to buy a ticket for? "<<endl;
  getline(cin, ride);
  
  cout<<"How old are you?"<<endl;
  cin>>age;

  //functions
  
  //ride
  if (ride == "Ferris Wheel"){
    rp = rp + 75.00;
    fer = true;
  }
  
  if (ride == "Bumper Cars"){
    rp = rp + 50.00;
    bump = true;
  }
  
  if (ride == "Zipper"){
    rp = rp + 100.00;
    zip = true;
  }
  
  if (ride == "The Pirate Ship"){
    rp = rp + 75.00;
    pir = true;
  }
  
  //age
  
  //ferris wheel
  if (fer = true){
    if (age >= 0 && age <= 7){
        cout<<"Do you have a companion that is at least 18 years old? Y/N";
        cin>>comp;
        if (comp == 'Y'){
            td = td + .20;
          }
        else{
            cout<<"You need a companion that is at least 18 years old.";
        }
      }
    else if (age >= 8 && age <= 12){
        td = td + .10;
    }
  
    else if(age >= 13 && age <= 20 ){
        td = td + 0.08;
    }
    
    else if(age > 20 && age < 60){
        td = td + 0.05;
    }
    
  }
  
  //bumper car
  if(bump = true){
    if (age >= 0 && age <= 7){
        cout<<"Do you have a companion that is at least 18 years old? Y/N";
        cin>>comp;
        if (comp == 'Y'){
            td = td + .20;
          }
        else{
            cout<<"You need a companion that is at least 18 years old.";
        }
      }
    
    else if (age >= 8 && age <= 12){
        td = td + .10;
    }
  
    else if(age >= 13 && age <= 20 ){
        td = td + 0.08;
    }
    
    else if(age > 20 && age < 60){
        td = td + 0.05;
    }
    
    else if(age > 60){
        td = td + .20;
    }
  }
  
  //zipline
  if (zip = true){
    if (age >= 0 && age <= 7){
        cout<<"Do you have a companion that is at least 18 years old? Y/N";
        cin>>comp;
        if (comp == 'Y'){
            td = td + .20;
      }
    else{
        cout<<"You need a companion that is at least 18 years old.";
        }
      }
    td = td + 0.10;
  }
  
  // pirate ship
  if (pir = true){
    if (age >= 0 && age <= 7){
    cout<<"Do you have a companion that is at least 18 years old? Y/N";
    cin>>comp;
        if (comp == 'Y'){
            td = td + .20;
          }
        else{
            cout<<"You need a companion that is at least 18 years old.";
        }
      }
      
    else if (age >= 8 && age <= 12){
        td = td + .10;
    }
  
    else if(age >= 13 && age <= 20 ){
        td = td + 0.08;
    }
    
    else if(age > 20 && age < 60){
        td = td + 0.05;
    }
    
    
    
  }

   // maths jaajbjabjabjaj B(
   
   cout<<fer<<endl;
   cout<<bump<<endl;
   cout<<zip<<endl;
   cout<<pir<<endl;
   cout<<td<<endl;
   cout<<rp<<endl;
   cout<<td<<endl;
   
   god = rp * td;
   cout<<"discount computed: "<<god<<endl;
   
   sp = rp - god;
   cout<<"sub pirce jajagnkfgdf: "<<sp<<endl;
   
   tap = sp * 0.05;
   cout<<"tap: "<<tap;
   
   ta = sp + tap;
   cout<<"ta: "<<ta;
   
    
    
  
  
  }
```

input for ride: The Pirate Ship
input for age: 9

output i get from code:
discount i get from code: 30
partial price : 45
total price : 47.25

output i should be getting from code:
discount i get from code: 7.5
partial price : 67.5
total price : 70.875

Comment: please include input output and expected output in the question

Comment: you are accessing uninitialized values `rp = rp + 75.00;` , causing undefined behavior

Comment: you also do not initialize the other variables and `fer = true` is assignment not comparison

Comment: pay attention to compiler warnings. With the right settings your code does not compile: https://godbolt.org/z/TE5qe36j9

Comment: Thanks!! I got to fix the problem !!

Answer (score 4):

I think this is because you didn't initialize your boolean variables. There is no single line, where you set "false". So that, they get random values, i.e. any non-zero value is considered as "true".

Comment: thats one issue, but not *the* issue. The condition in `if ( zip = true)` evaluates to `true` whether `zip` is initialized or not

Answer (score 3):

1. Set default value for booleans  `bool fer = false, bump = false, zip = false, pir = false, test = false;`
2. You are using `if` wrong.

   if (zip = true) // if zip equals true`.`

   if (zip == true) // if zip equals true`?`
3. Use else if

   //ride
   if (ride == "Ferris Wheel"){
   rp = rp + 75.00;
   fer = true;
   }

   else if (ride == "Bumper Cars"){
   rp = rp + 50.00;
   bump = true;
   }...

The ride cannot equal "Ferris Wheel" and "Bumper Cars" same time.